# restoring mongo database from dump

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am not able to get the correct command to issue in order to restore a mongodb from a dump dir.
Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

```js
appParent$ ls
dir1 dir2 dump

appParent$ ls dump/
meteor

appParent$ mongorestore --maintainInsertionOrder -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

error:

> using default 'dump' directory
>   building a list of collections to restore from dump dir
>   don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/meteor", skipping...
>   done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the directory name is the default you don't need further arguments. Just run `mongorestore`.

```
appParent$ ls
dir1 dir2 dump

appParent$ mongorestore --port 3001
```

Comment: That still gives the same error I mentioned in the comments to Fabio's answer

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the `-d` (database) parameter I think you may need to explicitly send the final `path` argument

So the command would be (considering you are in the folder containing the `dump` folder):

`$ mongorestore --maintainInsertionOrder -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/meteor`

Comment: When I do that, I get "don't know what to do with subdirectory "dump/meteor/dbais2", skipping..."