# Shipping your software with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I made an app which uses mongodb. What is the correct approach in shipping it?

The target users are not tech savvy people, actually, took me a while to create the users and get it working. But since I did that long time ago, and only once. I've already forgotten how to do it.

So what would be the easiest way for a user get my app, and have mongodb set up?

I used ReactiveMongo, and everything is wired properly already, so it has to be mongo, or compatible with this driver.

Few ideas on how I think this could be done:

1. Host this app online. (easiest), the user wouldn't need to install anything, just access the app through his browser.
   Problem: Since this is a POS app, it has to be 100% up. We can't rely on unreliable internet connection.
2. Embedded MongoDB? Is there something as good as SqlLite, but for mongo and works with ReactiveMongo?
3. Create a script to install mongodb from scratch, and configure with users and roles. (Any ideas / Examples for this?)

If there are better ways than what I mentioned above, please share

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to reach a wide variety of customers you should provide as many options as possible.

- Idea 1 sound good, no doubt you should have an online app, it can
  serve as a Demo that prospects can use when they are looking for a
  new POS. There are many benefits, Lower cost of entry, Pay as you go, upgrades, uptime and security, Work anywhere.
- Between 2 and 3 I lean towards 3, create an installer that deploys
  everything they need and provide a database dump with all the users
  and roles and restore that as part of the installation script, there are other SO questions covering that topic:
  [mongodb backup role - mongodump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021982/mongodb-backup-role-mongodump)
  [restoring mongo database from dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651410/restoring-mongo-database-from-dump)

Comment: For demo purposes I hosted it online. As for option 3, I don't know yet how I would create a cross-platform script to download and install. Meanwhile, I created a basic .json to create the users + initial data. Tested in an old win7-32 bits laptop, found out that this is needed `--storageEngine "mmapv1"` to run mongo server.  Then testing on a friend's mac, installing through teamviewer. Some spectacular problem just happens... No idea how to even google that problem ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So while I think #3 is best in terms of performance/maintenance, it is also the hardest to do. You'd have to consider what OS, version, arch.. and see which version of mongodb it supports. Option #2 however, should probably work with no problems. I did find sqlite equivalent to mongo, but I have yet found one that is "production ready".

Comment: This is a topic of much discussion companies spend countless hours doing research on this, but one thing everyone agrees on is that SaaS is here to stay.

Comment: You will have to do the research and decide what  OS/version & arch to support, maybe you should tackle just a few... but I do not agree that #3 is best in terms of performance/maintenance, on the contrary you have absolutely no control over the performance or maintenance of someones hardware, Windows for example they could have other applications installed that conflict with yours, antivirus and firewalls are notorious for causing conflicts.

Comment: You mention "Option #2 should probably work with no problems" that is a huge ***probably*** and just like you found out there are many beta options, and you are just scratching the surface once you start testing them you could find out they might not work with ReactiveMongo or partially work, causing you to go back and refactor tons of code.

Comment: You're right, supporting only a selected few might be the best for now. At least to start. Just now I tried testing on a Windows Vista machine, and before I could set up mongo, I found out that my app only supports win7+. Thank you very much for your insights.

Comment: Do your research see what's your intended market like, and make a decision from that. _ Something else you should consider is providing customers with the hardware, that way you know exactly where your software is installed.